# org.json.JSONException: No value for senses

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make an English Dictionary using the Oxford API. I made this according to docs and resources found on the web. But I got this issue `"org.json.JSONException: No value for senses"` and I don't why. Wherever I looked I couldn't find reason of this issue. I'll give you my `MainActivity` and `request class`. Can anyone help me?

MainActiviy:

```
package com.alitalhacoban.english_dictionary;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;

    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        url = dictionaryEntries();


    }

    public void find(View view){

        MyDictionaryRequest myDictionaryRequest = new MyDictionaryRequest(this);
        myDictionaryRequest.execute(url);

    }

    private String dictionaryEntries() {
        final String language = "en-gb";
        final String word = "Ace";
        final String fields = "pronunciations";
        final String strictMatch = "false";
        final String word_id = word.toLowerCase();
        return "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/" + language + "/" + word_id + "?" + "fields=" + fields + "&strictMatch=" + strictMatch;
    }
}
```

Request class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MyDictionaryRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    Context context;

    MyDictionaryRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    final String app_id = "127ae33f";
    final String app_key = "e42c0fccfe30223fb9ec02e12ae8c8a9";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_id", app_id);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_key", app_key);


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String def = "";
        try {
            JSONObject js = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray results = js.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject lentries = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray la = lentries.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");
                for (int j = 0; j < la.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject entries = la.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONArray e = entries.getJSONArray("entries");
                    for (int k = 0; k < e.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject senses = e.getJSONObject(k);
                        JSONArray s = senses.getJSONArray("senses");
                        JSONObject d = e.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONArray de = d.getJSONArray("definitions");
                        def = de.getString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("def", def);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: add the raw JSON here so we can find which node you missed

Answer (score 0):

try to validate the "senses" with senses.has("senses") before use it and then parse it with optjsonarray or optjsonobject for this type and check this key or check at backend side from where what value getting in json response.